# boost doesn't bind to member function even using this

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind

I am trying to use `boost::bind` with a `boost::function` using this.
It seems a trivial example but I cannot make it work. Can you help me?

Is it because it is not allowed or am I doing something wrong?

```
// .h
class MyClass{
publc:
    void DoSomething( 
        const std::string& a,
        const std::string& b);
    void DoABind();

}

//.cpp
void MyClass::DoABind(){

    boost::function< void( const std::string& , const std::string& ) > callback( 
        boost::bind(
               &MyClass::DoSomething,
                 this ));

        // this line doesn't compile!!!
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `bind(&MyClass::DoSomething, this, _1, _2)`. I don't have a boost installation to test with though.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to use the parameter placeholders. Try this:

```
boost::function< void( const std::string& , const std::string& ) > callback(
    boost::bind(
           &MyClass::DoSomething,
             this, _1, _2 ));
```

This compiles on gcc 4.4.1 with boost 1.41.